# UnauthorizedAccessException - Trying to serialize JSON to a file

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I am trying to produce a JSON file after parsing it.

In the code below, I am choosing the path to where the specified JSON file is going to appear.

```
public class Movie 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}

class Parsing
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Just a movie object for the sake of testing
        Movie movie = new Movie
        {
            Name = "Bad Boys",
            Year = 1995
        };

        try
        {
            // serialize JSON to a string and then write string to a file
            File.WriteAllText(@"c:\\Users\\LOrdBenche\\source\\repos\\parsingTest\\parsingTest\\producedJSON", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(movie));

            // serialize JSON directly to a file
            using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(@"c:\\Users\\LOrdBenche\\source\\repos\\parsingTest\\parsingTest\\producedJSON"))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.Serialize(file, movie);
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

However, the issue is that I keep having an `UnauthorizedAccessException`. I have given access to the folder and I have also tried running the program as an administrator.

Everything I found online suggested those two methods, yet they didn't work.

Comment: Please update your question with the full exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are both using a [verbatim string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) (`@""`) and escaping your path's backslashes. The `@` before a string literal will cause it to ignore escaped backslashes. So it's literally trying to write to `c:\\Users\\LOrdBenche\\source\\repos\\parsingTest\\parsingTest\\producedJSON`, which is an invalid path in Windows.

On top of that, you are only providing a folder in the path. [`File.WriteAllText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`File.CreateText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.createtext?view=netframework-4.7.2) require a file name and file extension as well.

Also, you should probably move your path to a `const` variable:

```
const string path = @"c:\Users\LOrdBenche\source\repos\parsingTest\parsingTest\producedJSON\test.json";

// ...

File.WriteAllText(path, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(movie));

// ...

using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(path))

// ...
```

Comment: Thank you, it was the @. Also, I was going to do create a const variable but thanks for the tip either way!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code should work. 
You could try to open the command prompt and type

```
cd c:\Users\LOrdBenche\source\repos\parsingTest\parsingTest\producedJSON
```

then

```
dir > test.txt
```

If you get an "Access is denied" message, it's because you really don't have sufficient rights to write into that folder.